# Is there any Objective-C equivalent for "Buffer" class in Java?

Tags: java, objective-c, ios, buffer

I am trying to find any equivalent class or library for the "Buffer" object in Objective C.
Here is the documentation of the "Buffer" class in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html
I need it in objective-C.
Thank you.

Comment: Not inside the SDK but it seems trivial to implement...

Comment: what about using NSData?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at [NSMutableData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/Reference/NSMutableData.html) or [NSData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSData).

NSData and its mutable subclass NSMutableData provide data objects, object-oriented wrappers for byte buffers. Data objects let simple allocated buffers (that is, data with no embedded pointers) take on the behavior of Foundation objects.

Answer (score 4):

Look at [NSMutableData](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/Reference/NSMutableData.html)